# How to control the FarClipPlane of a reflection camera in Unity3d (4.3f1)

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine, shader

I have the following scenario:
I used http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MirrorReflection2 to add a mirror to my scene. Then I noticed that the amount of draw-calls skyrocketed to insane numbers (about the entire amount of draw-calls required to draw the entire scene).

I noticed that the reflection script generates a temporary camera to render the reflection texture, so I tried to lower the Far Clip Plane of that camera (in code) but it had no effect.

I've made a dozen attempts at reducing the Far Clip Plane and playing around with occlusion culling for that camera however it seems resistant to my changes. (I saw that the reflection camera was being recreated every frame so I tried caching it, but that didn't help either)

My updated code is :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// This is in fact just the Water script from Pro Standard Assets,
// just with refraction stuff removed.

[ExecuteInEditMode] // Make mirror live-update even when not in play mode
public class MirrorReflection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera ReflectionCamera;
    public bool m_DisablePixelLights = true;
    public int m_TextureSize = 1024;
    public float m_ClipPlaneOffset = 0.07f;

    public LayerMask m_ReflectLayers = -1;

    private Hashtable m_ReflectionCameras = new Hashtable(); // Camera -> Camera table

    private RenderTexture m_ReflectionTexture = null;
    private int m_OldReflectionTextureSize = 0;

    private static bool s_InsideRendering = false;

    // This is called when it's known that the object will be rendered by some
    // camera. We render reflections and do other updates here.
    // Because the script executes in edit mode, reflections for the scene view
    // camera will just work!
    public void OnWillRenderObject()
    {
        if( !enabled || !renderer || !renderer.sharedMaterial || !renderer.enabled )
            return;

        Camera cam = Camera.current;
        if( !cam )
            return;

        // Safeguard from recursive reflections.        
        if( s_InsideRendering )
            return;
        s_InsideRendering = true;

        Camera reflectionCamera;
        if(m_ReflectionCameras.ContainsKey(cam))
        {
            reflectionCamera = m_ReflectionCameras[cam] as Camera;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Creating and Updating Reflection Camera");
            CreateMirrorObjects(cam, out reflectionCamera);
            UpdateCameraModes( cam, reflectionCamera );

            reflectionCamera.farClipPlane = 4.0f;
            m_ReflectionCameras[cam] = reflectionCamera;
            this.ReflectionCamera = reflectionCamera;
        }

        // find out the reflection plane: position and normal in world space
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        Vector3 normal = transform.up;

        // Optionally disable pixel lights for reflection
        int oldPixelLightCount = QualitySettings.pixelLightCount;
        if( m_DisablePixelLights )
            QualitySettings.pixelLightCount = 0;

        //UpdateCameraModes( cam, reflectionCamera );

        // Render reflection
        // Reflect camera around reflection plane
        float d = -Vector3.Dot (normal, pos) - m_ClipPlaneOffset;
        Vector4 reflectionPlane = new Vector4 (normal.x, normal.y, normal.z, d);

        Matrix4x4 reflection = Matrix4x4.zero;
        CalculateReflectionMatrix (ref reflection, reflectionPlane);
        Vector3 oldpos = cam.transform.position;
        Vector3 newpos = reflection.MultiplyPoint( oldpos );
        reflectionCamera.worldToCameraMatrix = cam.worldToCameraMatrix * reflection;

        // Setup oblique projection matrix so that near plane is our reflection
        // plane. This way we clip everything below/above it for free.
        Vector4 clipPlane = CameraSpacePlane( reflectionCamera, pos, normal, 1.0f );
        Matrix4x4 projection = cam.projectionMatrix;
        //CalculateObliqueMatrix (ref projection, clipPlane);
        reflectionCamera.projectionMatrix = projection;

        reflectionCamera.cullingMask = ~(1<<4) & m_ReflectLayers.value; // never render water layer
        reflectionCamera.targetTexture = m_ReflectionTexture;
        GL.SetRevertBackfacing (true);
        reflectionCamera.transform.position = newpos;
        Vector3 euler = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
        reflectionCamera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, euler.y, euler.z);
        Debug.Log(reflectionCamera.farClipPlane);
        reflectionCamera.Render();
        reflectionCamera.transform.position = oldpos;
        GL.SetRevertBackfacing (false);
        Material[] materials = renderer.sharedMaterials;
        foreach( Material mat in materials ) {
            if( mat.HasProperty("_ReflectionTex") )
                mat.SetTexture( "_ReflectionTex", m_ReflectionTexture );
        }

        // Set matrix on the shader that transforms UVs from object space into screen
        // space. We want to just project reflection texture on screen.
        Matrix4x4 scaleOffset = Matrix4x4.TRS(
            new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f) );
        Vector3 scale = transform.lossyScale;
        Matrix4x4 mtx = transform.localToWorldMatrix * Matrix4x4.Scale( new Vector3(1.0f/scale.x, 1.0f/scale.y, 1.0f/scale.z) );
        mtx = scaleOffset * cam.projectionMatrix * cam.worldToCameraMatrix * mtx;
        foreach( Material mat in materials ) {
            mat.SetMatrix( "_ProjMatrix", mtx );
        }

        // Restore pixel light count
        if( m_DisablePixelLights )
            QualitySettings.pixelLightCount = oldPixelLightCount;

        s_InsideRendering = false;
    }


    // Cleanup all the objects we possibly have created
    void OnDisable()
    {
        if( m_ReflectionTexture ) {
            DestroyImmediate( m_ReflectionTexture );
            m_ReflectionTexture = null;
        }
        foreach( DictionaryEntry kvp in m_ReflectionCameras )
            DestroyImmediate( ((Camera)kvp.Value).gameObject );
        m_ReflectionCameras.Clear();
    }


    private void UpdateCameraModes( Camera src, Camera dest )
    {
        if( dest == null )
            return;
        // set camera to clear the same way as current camera
        dest.clearFlags = src.clearFlags;
        dest.backgroundColor = src.backgroundColor;        
        if( src.clearFlags == CameraClearFlags.Skybox )
        {
            Skybox sky = src.GetComponent(typeof(Skybox)) as Skybox;
            Skybox mysky = dest.GetComponent(typeof(Skybox)) as Skybox;
            if( !sky || !sky.material )
            {
                mysky.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                mysky.enabled = true;
                mysky.material = sky.material;
            }
        }
        // update other values to match current camera.
        // even if we are supplying custom camera&projection matrices,
        // some of values are used elsewhere (e.g. skybox uses far plane)
        dest.farClipPlane = src.farClipPlane;
        dest.nearClipPlane = src.nearClipPlane;
        dest.orthographic = src.orthographic;
        dest.fieldOfView = src.fieldOfView;
        dest.aspect = src.aspect;
        dest.orthographicSize = src.orthographicSize;
    }

    // On-demand create any objects we need
    private void CreateMirrorObjects( Camera currentCamera, out Camera reflectionCamera )
    {
        reflectionCamera = null;

        // Reflection render texture
        if( !m_ReflectionTexture || m_OldReflectionTextureSize != m_TextureSize )
        {
            if( m_ReflectionTexture )
                DestroyImmediate( m_ReflectionTexture );
            m_ReflectionTexture = new RenderTexture( m_TextureSize, m_TextureSize, 16 );
            m_ReflectionTexture.name = "__MirrorReflection" + GetInstanceID();
            m_ReflectionTexture.isPowerOfTwo = true;
            m_ReflectionTexture.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
            m_OldReflectionTextureSize = m_TextureSize;
        }

        // Camera for reflection
        reflectionCamera = m_ReflectionCameras[currentCamera] as Camera;
        if( !reflectionCamera ) // catch both not-in-dictionary and in-dictionary-but-deleted-GO
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject( "Mirror Refl Camera id" + GetInstanceID() + " for " + currentCamera.GetInstanceID(), typeof(Camera), typeof(Skybox) );
            reflectionCamera = go.camera;
            reflectionCamera.enabled = false;
            reflectionCamera.transform.position = transform.position;
            reflectionCamera.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            reflectionCamera.gameObject.AddComponent("FlareLayer");
            go.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
            m_ReflectionCameras[currentCamera] = reflectionCamera;
        }        
    }

    // Extended sign: returns -1, 0 or 1 based on sign of a
    private static float sgn(float a)
    {
        if (a > 0.0f) return 1.0f;
        if (a < 0.0f) return -1.0f;
        return 0.0f;
    }

    // Given position/normal of the plane, calculates plane in camera space.
    private Vector4 CameraSpacePlane (Camera cam, Vector3 pos, Vector3 normal, float sideSign)
    {
        Vector3 offsetPos = pos + normal * m_ClipPlaneOffset;
        Matrix4x4 m = cam.worldToCameraMatrix;
        Vector3 cpos = m.MultiplyPoint( offsetPos );
        Vector3 cnormal = m.MultiplyVector( normal ).normalized * sideSign;
        return new Vector4( cnormal.x, cnormal.y, cnormal.z, -Vector3.Dot(cpos,cnormal) );
    }

    // Adjusts the given projection matrix so that near plane is the given clipPlane
    // clipPlane is given in camera space. See article in Game Programming Gems 5.
    private static void CalculateObliqueMatrix (ref Matrix4x4 projection, Vector4 clipPlane)
    {
        Vector4 q = projection.inverse * new Vector4(
            sgn(clipPlane.x),
            sgn(clipPlane.y),
            1.0f,
            1.0f
        );
        Vector4 c = clipPlane * (2.0F / (Vector4.Dot (clipPlane, q)));
        // third row = clip plane - fourth row
        projection[2] = c.x - projection[3];
        projection[6] = c.y - projection[7];
        projection[10] = c.z - projection[11];
        projection[14] = c.w - projection[15];
    }

    // Calculates reflection matrix around the given plane
    private static void CalculateReflectionMatrix (ref Matrix4x4 reflectionMat, Vector4 plane)
    {
        reflectionMat.m00 = (1F - 2F*plane[0]*plane[0]);
        reflectionMat.m01 = (   - 2F*plane[0]*plane[1]);
        reflectionMat.m02 = (   - 2F*plane[0]*plane[2]);
        reflectionMat.m03 = (   - 2F*plane[3]*plane[0]);

        reflectionMat.m10 = (   - 2F*plane[1]*plane[0]);
        reflectionMat.m11 = (1F - 2F*plane[1]*plane[1]);
        reflectionMat.m12 = (   - 2F*plane[1]*plane[2]);
        reflectionMat.m13 = (   - 2F*plane[3]*plane[1]);

        reflectionMat.m20 = (   - 2F*plane[2]*plane[0]);
        reflectionMat.m21 = (   - 2F*plane[2]*plane[1]);
        reflectionMat.m22 = (1F - 2F*plane[2]*plane[2]);
        reflectionMat.m23 = (   - 2F*plane[3]*plane[2]);

        reflectionMat.m30 = 0F;
        reflectionMat.m31 = 0F;
        reflectionMat.m32 = 0F;
        reflectionMat.m33 = 1F;
    }
}
```

The `Debug.Log` line near the `reflectionCamera.render(...);` prints `4` as expected, but neither the amount of draw-calls nor what is viewed in the mirror change.

Comment: The code sets a custom `projectionMatrix` on the reflection camera. I think that's why the `farClipPlane` value isn't used. You'll probably have to bake the far clip plane into the projection matrix somehow.

Comment: Hmm, cool, I'll try to play around with that..

Comment: In a limited environment test it looks like modifying the `farClipPlane` before the `projectionMatrix` is created seems to work, I've yet to try it in the full scene, I'll update when I do.

Comment: okay, nwellnhof, this indeed seems to be the way to modify the `farClipPlane`, feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer: The code sets a custom projectionMatrix on the reflection camera. I think that's why the farClipPlane value isn't used. You'll probably have to bake the far clip plane into the projection matrix somehow.

Comment: Yeah, all I had to do was add this line:
`reflectionCamera.farClipPlane = this.FarClipPlane;`
 before this line: 
`Vector4 clipPlane = CameraSpacePlane( reflectionCamera, pos, normal, 1.0f );` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Even messing with the far clip plane settings - I ended up with infinite distance in my reflections - if anyone else is looking for a solution to this, one option is enabling layer cull distances on your reflection camera:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html

If you set the distances to your required far clip plane, and set layer cull spherical (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullSpherical.html) to true, you can have it clip by spherical distance from the camera.

It's not the exact same culling as the main camera so it may result in other artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: This is a miraculous solution.  You added 50fps to my game!